# Чтение по маске в директории c readFile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Содержимое директории:

```
/some/dir/
       file.tar.bz2
       file.tar.bz2.MD5
```

Задав переменную:

```
def md5 = readFile "/some/dir/*.MD5"
```

Получаем в консоли:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /some/dir/*.MD5
```

Comment: То, что вы ищете, называется shell expansion и работает в bash. Когда вы пытаетесь что-то прочитать напрямую в языке программирования, ЯП, как правило, скармливает путь к файлу напрямую ОС, что и происходит здесь. Вам нужно либо заранее указывать название файла, либо вручную итерировать содержимое директории, либо использовать glob (к сожалению, не знаю как с этим в груви)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, не могу в данном случае имя файла четко задать (уверен, это решаемо, но на данном этапе -никак). В языках не силен, усиленно в цейтноте осваиваю Jenkins pipeline+Grovvy. Можно подробнее про glob?

Comment: glob - это название для функционала нахождения файла по маске (часть shell expansion, присутствует, как правило, в любом языке)

Comment: Спасибо, гляну.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `readFile` читает только **один** файл и по **относительному** пути:

> Reads a file from a relative path (with root in current directory, usually workspace) and returns its content as a plain string.

[Pipeline: Basic Steps](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Basic+Steps+Plugin)

Если вам нужно читать много файлов, пропустите их через `findFiles`:

```
def md5 = []

dir("/some/dir/") {
    findFiles(glob: '*.MD5').each { file ->
        md5 += readFile(file.path)
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что `findFiles` тоже работает с **относительными** путями, поэтому я использовал `dir()`. На выходе получите массив в переменной `md5`, с которым дальше можете работать через `foreach` или `.each`.